# Subclass of NSProxy

Tags: xamarin, monomac

I'm porting objective-c library to mono one.There are several classes have interfaces based on NSProxy. But monomac has no NSProxy. Can anyone out there help me to figure out the best way to implement NSProxy, or maybe someone have experience to do that?

Thanks in advance.